# Webpage won't show certain characters

Tags: character-encoding

I'm noticing that in places where our site uses special characters on a webpage, such as ¡ or ¿ or even "special quotes" (like MS-word) it displays this funky � character

Is there something I can to do fix this? Is this a charset thing?

I know I could use html entities, such as

```
&iexcl;
```

But, I wanted to see if there was something else to address this since I notice some other sites don't need to use the special code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to use the following meta tag?

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: Yeah I have, still no luck. I'm wondering if it matters that the text is being pulled from a database?

Comment: have you tried it with other browsers? try to remove meta tag and play with the encoding menu in your browser to see if something happens, also check you table collation. (This all is purely empiric, I had the same problem but could solve it placing right meta tag, btw, also check your source code, you can have meta tag written twice)